# how to add two different controls (checkbox and combobox) as list item in ListBox wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to bind the **listbox** with list of items retreived from database. Each list item is displayed as checkbox in listbox.

```
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <CheckBox Content="{Binding Name}" IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked}"/>
     </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate>
```

Along with the checkbox, I also need to add a checkbox as a list item.
Could anyone let me know as to how this can be done?

Comment: When do you add a check box, and when a combo box?

Comment: i have only added a checkbox but i also need to add a combobox. But i can add only control in datatemplate.. so i get an error. is there any way i can do  it

Comment: Embed your controls in a container (e.g. a `StackPanel`).

Answer (score 0):

[DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) options within WPF this allow a very small amount of backend code to take care of all the selections for you. This allows you to make use of this code from within an MVVM structure without any issues, and while making the front end extremely easy to manage without complicating the back end code.

[here is a sample.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/418250/WPF-Based-Dynamic-DataTemplateSelector)

Answer (score 0):

Use [DataTemplateSelector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datatemplateselector.aspx) if you want to use two different visuals as list items.